# Can I transfer the balance to the same address on Polkadot?

Tags: polkadot, balances, transactions, transfer

Can I send a balance when my from address and to address are the same?

The reason for asking these questions is to deal with exceptions during development.

Of course, I can test it myself, but I don't have a test coin. haha

we'll have to test it out one more time before it's released, but do you have any information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, and you will pay for the fees of such a transaction.
And take care of not reaping your account when doing this interaction.What can be avoided by using `KeepAlive` when transacting any balance between two accounts.

But as you say this is something that you could have tested easily in one of the test public networks:

- [Westend RPC](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.pinknode.io%2Fwestend%2Fexplorer#/explorer)
- [Westend Faucet](https://matrix.to/#/#westend_faucet:matrix.org)
- [Rococo RPC](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-rpc.polkadot.io#/explorer)
- [Rococo Faucet](https://matrix.to/#/#rococo-faucet:matrix.org)